# "Nearest neighbor"-like interpolation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, interpolation

This is a small thing but has been bothering me for a while now, so I thought I would let the crowd solving begin :)

I have a matrix with timestamps and a corresponding logical value (or 1/0), i.e.

```
of = [-inf 0 10 15 190 inf; 1 0 0 1 1 0]'
```

and an another time vector, e.g.

```
t = 0:0.1:1e3;
```

or whatever, you get the point :)

Now how do I (read: would you) inter-/extrapolate the logical infomation in `of` so it matches the timestamps in `t`, but with the interpolated logicals always assuming the last or current value, not a future one?

Don't know if that makes sense, but here is the expected output given `of` and `t2`

```
t2 = [0 5 14 16]
output = [0 0 10 15; 0 0 0 1]'
```

where the first column of `output` is the time of `of` used in interpolation. If I use `interp1` and the 'nearest' algorithm, it will give

```
interp1(of(:,1), of, t2, 'nearest')
output = [0 10 15 15; 0 0 1 1]'
```

which is not exactly what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your vectors are sorted you could try that, which seems to work with your example although I did not tested it extensively:

```
of=[-inf 0 10 15 190 inf; 1 0 0 1 1 0]';
t2 = [0 5 14 16];
index=floor(interp1(of(:,1),(1:size(of,1))',t2'));
output=of(index,:);
```

Hope it helps.

The default method used by interp1 is `linear`, which works best with your condition because you do not want the "nearest" neighbor but the first lower or equal neighbor (as far as I understand this). Therefore a simple truncation of the interpolated timestamps index gives you the result.

Comment: F*** me thats the stuff! :D
Some times you can just get lost in complexity, I guess that is what happend here :)
Also, infs can be ignored if one rethinks the problem, so this will work.